# How can i display image from component to another using click on it?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

i have a div which is contain an image and i need to view it in another div which is in another component (in angular )
i'm starting with this code:

**Update:**

```
image: ImageData;
@Output() sendimage = new EventEmitter<ImageData>();
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAhKQ.png]

Comment: Could you explain your problem in details with your code.

Comment: i'm trying to write code but it's not work , the problem is about binding

Comment: Please provide me your code. I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: please see the image i added above..

Comment: I edited your question.

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like? or at least the function this is in?
Also, have you seen : https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try this

**Child component** e.g. app-child

```
@Output() sendImage: EventEmitter<ImageData>;
constructor() {
        this.sendImage= new EventEmitter<ImageData>();
}
send() {
  this.sendImage.emit(this.image);
}
```

**Parent component** Template

```
<app-child
 (sendImage) = "receiveIamge($event)"
></app-child>
```

And its controller:

```
receiveImage(image: ImageData) {
     // your process here
}
```

Comment: No, If you want share imagedata in two brother component, you should make data in parent component and in two childs you can use @Input()